# What happened to the writing staff on Frasier in the last few seasons?

Tags: frasier

I've heard vague comments to the effect that the writing staff of Frasier got shaken up considerably during the last few seasons. Specifically, I heard that many of the writers of seasons 1-7 left, and then came back for season 11. Is this accurate? If so, is there any information about how the season 8-10 writers planned to resolve the season 10 cliffhanger, with Roz leaving KACL?

Comment: Where are you hearing such rumours? You can check IMDb's list of cast and crew to see if the writers did change.

Comment: I don't know about the last few seasons, but I'm just streaming the whole series on Netflix and watching it for the first time. Seems to me the writing goes downhill in season 5. Prior to that season, the humor is mostly urbane and witty with occasional brilliant physical comedy from David Hyde Pierce. Season 5 is like watching vaudeville or the 3 Stooges. If it keeps on like this, I won't be able to tolerate the whole series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Frasier_writers) is a list of writers and the episodes they wrote. There is an article [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Frasier?from=Main.Frasier) that discusses the writers of season 11 called season 10 a misfire.

This probably means that the producers wanted a creative sea-change to get the show back on track. The original trajectory for season 11 is unclear, but [here's](http://www.emmytvlegends.org/interviews/people/christopher-lloyd-writer) a half hour interview with writer Christopher Lloyd.